# PHP header redirection not working after installing xdebug

Tags: php, header, xdebug

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.com/';
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

The xdebug setting in php.ini is:

```
zend_extension=path_to_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

The above `header()` redirection will work as long as I remove the xdebug setting.

Anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=532

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in xdebug, you may want to check your xdebug version and update it to the latest.
If I remember correctly, there were a few postings of the same issue at http://bugs.xdebug.org
They have been resolved.

--Edit--
Looks like someone else actually searched and found it at http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=532  as I was typing my original response.